# Adjusted Rand Index and confusion matrix not making sense?

Tags: r, clustering, accuracy

I suspect there is a very obvious answer to this question that I am missing.

I have a confusion matrix (see below). The X axis contain the true classes of a dataset, while the Y axis contains predicted classes following a K means iteration. Now according to the matrix, the algorithm has been very poor at predicting the true classes of any datapoint.

[image]

I also calculated the Adjusted rand index, which gave a value of 0.94. That would suggest however that the two prediction are very closely aligned?

```
 table(GeneCluster$cluster,classer)
 adjustedRandIndex(GeneCluster$cluster, classer)
```

Have I misinterpreted or missed something stupid?

Answer (score 1):

Cluster numbers are arbitrary. Any permutation is equal.

What you are misinterpreting is that kmeans would "predict" the exact same label.

If your classes are "apple" and "banana", kmeans with k=3 would still "predict" clusters 1,2,3.

The whole concept of "prediction" here is misleading. Not every algorithm output is a prediction. I'd only use prediction for supervised learning.

Answer (score 0):

Anony-Mousse is correct; numeric cluster labels are arbitrary. It would be helpful to view the confusion matrix with the largest values possible on the diagonal -- in your case it is clear that cluster 1 by column and cluster 3 by row are very similar. This is equivalent to maximising the trace of the matrix, and I found some very helpful R  code [here](https://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/reordering-of-matrix-rows-to-maximize-the-sum-of-the-diagonal-td2062867.html), reproduced below:

```r
set.seed(66)
library("clue")

## Generate random clusters
c1 <- sample(1:5, 1000, replace=TRUE, prob=sample(seq(0.1, 0.5, by=0.1), 5))
## Generate perturbed (but similar) cluster labels
c2 <- ifelse(rnorm(1000) < 0.5, sample(c1), c1)
c2 <- as.numeric(factor(c2, levels = sample(5, 5)))

## Confusion matrix -- it is clear the there are large overlaps but
## difficult to see where as they are off-diagonal
table(c1, c2)
#>    c2
#> c1    1   2   3   4   5
#>   1  10 178  58  35  24
#>   2   8  53  37  97  14
#>   3  23  13  11   6   7
#>   4   7  11  30  19  64
#>   5  10  57 155  46  27

pMatrix.min <- function(A, B) {
  # finds the permutation P of A such that ||PA - B|| is minimum in Frobenius norm
  # Uses the linear-sum assignment problem (LSAP) solver in the "clue" package

  # Returns P%*%A and the permutation vector `pvec' such that
  # A[pvec, ] is the permutation of A closest to B
  n <- nrow(A)
  D <- matrix(NA, n, n)
  for (i in 1:n) {
    for (j in 1:n) {
      D[j, i] <- sum((B[j, ] - A[i, ]) ^ 2)
    } 
  }
  vec <- solve_LSAP(D)
  A[vec, ]
}

tab <- as.matrix(table(c1, c2))

d <- diag(1, nrow(tab)) # this choice of B maximizes the trace of permuted A

## Matrix with maximised trace/maximal diagonal component
pMatrix.min(tab, d)
#>    c2
#> c1    1   2   3   4   5
#>   3  23  13  11   6   7
#>   1  10 178  58  35  24
#>   5  10  57 155  46  27
#>   2   8  53  37  97  14
#>   4   7  11  30  19  64
```

I find this procedure very useful when comparing the output of clustering algorithms, as it helps you to see the combination of cluster labels which matches most closely, even when this is relatively hard to spot from the initial confusion matrix.